# Play Framework JsReads for object names and values

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-json

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
  "1992": "this is dog",
  "1883": "test string",
  "1732": "unknown",
  "2954": "future year"
}
```

Is there any way, using JSON `reads` to transform this JSON into a Scala case class? i.e. a `Seq[Years]` or a `Map[String, String]`, where a Year holds the year and the description.

For reference, this is how you define a `read` for a "simple" JSON structure:

```
{
  "name": "george",
  "age": 24
}
```

The implicit `JsReads`

```
implicit val dudeReads = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "age").read[Int]
) (Dude)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @Pranav's answer, but more concise:

```
Json.parse("""
    {
      "1992": "this is dog",
      "1883": "test string",
      "1732": "unknown",
      "2954": "future year"
    }
""").as[Map[String, String]]
```

yields

```
Map[String,String] = Map(1992 -> this is dog, 1883 -> test string, 1732 -> unknown, 2954 -> future year)
```

The underlying `Reads` are defined [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L869-L887).

Answer (score 4):

Convert your json string to JsValue and then use validate on the JsValue object.

```
scala> val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
 | {
 |   "1992": "this is dog",
 |   "1883": "test string",
 |   "1732": "unknown",
 |   "2954": "future year"
 | }
 | """)
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"1992":"this is dog","1883":"test string","1732":"unknown","2954":"future year"}

scala> val valid = json.validate[Map[String,String]]
valid: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Map[String,String]] = JsSuccess(Map(1992 -> this is dog, 1883 -> test string, 1732 -> unknown, 2954 -> future year),)

scala> valid match {
 | case s: JsSuccess[Map[String,String]] => println(s.get)
 | case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toJson(e).toString())
 | }
Map(1992 -> this is dog, 1883 -> test string, 1732 -> unknown, 2954 -> future year)
```

Comment: You can skip the validation and subsequent match by just writing `val result = json.as[Map[String, String]]`.

Comment: @Eric The as method will throw a `JsResultException` if the path is not found or the conversion is not possible. [Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt)